# IPv6 subnetting - coverting decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: networking, ipv6, subnet

I came across a question on IPv6 subnetting,

> You work as a branch network administrator of a large company with
>   offices in many cities around the world. The corporate network is
>   currently in the process of implementing global addresses for all
>   hosts. The central IT department provides you with the global address
>   space 3f04:4d12:95a5:a000::/52. Your network includes four subnets.
>
> Which address and network prefix should you assign the third subnet?

Since we need 4 segments, that means 2 bits, hence a mask of /52 + 2 = /54

The increments between subnets is 264 - 54 = 210

However, the increment must be in hexadecimal, and when I convert 210 to hexadecimal I get D2

```
Convert 210 to hexadecimal

210 / 16 = 13 R 2
13 / 16 = 0 R 13, i.e. D in hex
0 / 16 = 0 R 0
```

Which means address and network prefix of

```
Subnet 1 = 3f04:4d12:95a5:ad20::/54
Subnet 2 = 3f04:4d12:95a5:a1a4::/54
Subnet 3 = 3f04:4d12:95a5:a2148::/54
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct answer.

Here is the solution provided by the book (copy and paste)

If you have four subnets, you need to claim 2 bits for subnetting. In this case, the network prefix used in the subnetted space must be /52 + 2, or /54. For a /54 subnetting scheme, the increment between subnets is 264-54 or 210, which in hexadecimal is written as 400. The subnet 1 address must be 3f04:4d12:95a5:a000::/54, and then using the hexadecimal increment, you can determine that the subnet 2 address is 3f04:4d12:95a5:a400::/54, the subnet 3 address is 3f04:4d12:95a5:a800::/54, and the subnet 4 address is 3f04:4d12:95a5:ac00::/54.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the book, and what is the exact edition.

Comment: Configuring Windows Server 2008 Network Infrastructure, 2nd Edition. Tony Northrup, J.C. Mackin. This is for MS Exam 70-642. I copied and pasted the question from the CD that comes with the book.

Comment: The formatting looks clear on [safaribooksonline.com](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AzU7M.png).  It is 2 to the (64 -54)  which is 2 to the 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easy in binary. Lets just look at the 4th quartet (I really hate that name). Bits 49-64 of the address, since writing all 128 bits is painful.  I am going to use `()` to group each nibble and a  to represent the subnet boundary.

```
a000 = (1010) (0000)(0000)(0000)
```

So we want to break that into 4 subnets, and so we need 4 bits.

```
a000 = (1010)(00 00)(0000)(0000)
a400 = (1010)(01 00)(0000)(0000)
a800 = (1010)(10 00)(0000)(0000)
a800 = (1010)(11 00)(0000)(0000)
```

If you want to pick value to add to a000 it is going to be 0x0400 `(0100)(0000)(0000)` or in decimal 1024.

<strike>I really have no idea what all that `264 - 54 = 210` stuff is about in your book explanation.  It looks like total garbage to me.</strike>

Ok, I think I understand what is going on now.  Either you have omitted some formatting when you copy and pasted, or perhaps the formatting in your book is screwed up.

I am almost certain that the value isn't supposed to be 264 it is to be 2 raised to the 64th power (2<sup>62</sup> or 2^64).  The 210 isn't supposed to be a decimal value of 210, it is 2 raise to the 10th power (2<sup>10</sup>).  2<sup>10</sup> = (2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2) = 1024 or 0x0400 in hex.

Comment: now I understand. The online version of the book has poor formatting, hence all the confusion. Your answer makes total sense.